# Как получить результат запроса YII 2 (count relation)

Tags: php, yii2

На примере этого кода:

```
$books = Books::find()
->joinWith(['reviews'])
->select(['books.id','books.name', 'COUNT(reviews.id) as cnt'])
->groupBy('books.id')
->orderBy('books.name')
->all();
```

Как вывести(получить) id, name и количество всех отзывов (cnt)?

Comment: 'COUNT(DISTINCT(reviews.id)) as cnt'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и у обычного запроса, в переменной `$books` будет массив с объектами `Books`, только чтобы вывести `cnt` нужно создать публичный метод:

```
class Books extends ActiveRecord {

    public $cnt;

    //Дальше ваш класс

}
```

И потом просто получаете данные:

```
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo 'Book ID: ' . $book->id . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Book name: ' . $book->name . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Reviews: ' . $book->cnt . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо